# Protractor page objects error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, pageobjects

I'm building my angularjs protractor e2e test to the page objects pattern. I'm facing trouble with converting my script in to page object.

Here is my `conf.js`

```
// conf.js
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['employee.js']
}
```

Here is my `employee.js`

```
// spec.js
var EmpPageObject = require('./EmpPageObject.js');
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
  it('should have a title', function() {

    var empPageObject = new EmpPageObject();
    empPageObject.get();

    empPageObject.setName('mee');
    empPageObject.setPassword('123');

  });
});
```

Here is my `EmpPageObject.js`

```
var EmpPageObject = function() {

    var nameInput = element(by.model('login.user_name'));
    var passwordInput = element(by.model('login.password'));
    var addButton = element(by.css('.btn'));

    this.get = function() {
    browser.get('http://');
  };

  this.setName = function(name) {
    nameInput.sendKeys(name);
  };

  this.setPassword = function(password) {
    passwordInput.sendKeys(password);
  };

  addButton.click();

};
```

But, my script fails giving the following error.

```
Failures:
1) Protractor Demo App should have a title
  Message:
    Failed:  EmpPageObject is not defined
```

This may be a dumb question. But, I cannot find the error since this is my first test. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like you copy-paste code from here
https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/f9c8a37f7dbec1dccec2dde0bd6884ad7ae3f5c7/docs/tutorial.md

```
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
  it('should have a title', function() {
    browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');

    expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Super Calculator');
  });
});
```

Here is `protractor` try to get resource and check - is it have title.

This function return true or false to make test. In your case, function return `undefined`, it is equal to false, test fail and you get error message.

Comment: Tried to convert to page objects from http://www.protractortest.org/#/page-objects . But, how can I make this right? Can u explain more?

Comment: Sorry man, I was wrong, there is other issue. You have message  `Failed: EmpPageObject is not defined`, it mean that you did not define (import) `EmpPageObject`, and your test fail, because exception occured when you call `new EmpPageObject()`.

Comment: but, I clearly defined the `EmpPageObject` in the `EmpPageObject.js`. I don't get your point friend. :(

Comment: Okayyy. Got the point. added `var EmpPageObject = require('./EmpPageObject.js');` to the `employee.js` . But, Another error occured, ` EmpPageObject is not a constructor` . :(

Comment: Got the answer. Thanks :)